# Materialize Pushpin overflowing bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar, materialize, pushpin

I'm trying to achieve a "sticky" responsive sidebar.

I'm using Materialize Pushpin to do the trick (http://materializecss.com/pushpin.html)

I can't seem to get the bottom offset to work correctly. It breaks sometimes, and if the height of the content is smaller than the sidebar itself I get overflows..

I've created a codepen so You could better understand.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpXoOG

```
code
```

What would be the correct way to implement a sticky responsive sidebar with this layout, given that height of both sidebar and content can vary from small to large.

Thank You in advance, Stackoverflow! <3

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue by changing materialize pushpin for Sticky-Kit (http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) . Works great with very little setup.